# Gradle javadoc task fails in Java 10

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, java-10

When attempting to execute the `javadoc` task in my gradle build, the following message is printed out (along with a stacktrace that I can provide on request):

```
javadoc: error - An internal exception has occurred. 
    (com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder$BadClassFile: bad class file: /home/vtcakavsmoace/IdeaProjects/DiscordSRV2-Core/build/classes/java/main/com/discordsrv/core/auth/PlayerUserAuthenticator$1$1.class
  bad enclosing class for com.discordsrv.core.auth.PlayerUserAuthenticator$1$1: com.discordsrv.core.auth.PlayerUserAuthenticator$1
  Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.)
Please file a bug against the javadoc tool via the Java bug reporting page
(http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com)
for duplicates. Include error messages and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder$BadClassFile: bad class file: /home/vtcakavsmoace/IdeaProjects/DiscordSRV2-Core/build/classes/java/main/com/discordsrv/core/auth/PlayerUserAuthenticator$1$1.class
  bad enclosing class for com.discordsrv.core.auth.PlayerUserAuthenticator$1$1: com.discordsrv.core.auth.PlayerUserAuthenticator$1
  Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

The javadoc appears to be attempting to document an anonymous inner class of an anonymous inner class.

Upon further inspection in the build folder, you can see that that anonymous class simply isn't there:

[image: build dir]

And here is the only method containing an anonymous class in the file (reduced for clarity):

```
public void doSomething() {
    map.forEach((key, value) -> key.doSomething(response -> {
            invokeWithCallback(value, var, new FutureCallback<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final @Nullable Boolean result) {
                    ...
                    new Pair<Key, Value>() {
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(final @Nonnull Throwable t) {
                    ...
                }
            });
        }
    }));
}
```

How should I handle this to make sure the javadoc task can complete?

**EDIT:**

Did a little more exploring; removing the inner anonymous class allows the javadoc task to complete, so this anonymous instance seems to be the issue.

Comment: Not adding this to the question because I don't want to have a "plz fix meh codez" question, but I wanted to link the full error in action with all sources: https://ci.scarsz.me/job/DiscordSRV2-Core/138/console

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround:

Declare an inner class in which you perform the anonymous instantiation. This prevents javadoc from attempting to resolve the non-existent class file. In the format of the question:

```
public void doSomething() {
    map.forEach((key, value) -> key.doSomething(response -> {
            invokeWithCallback(value, var, new MyCallback(...));
        }
    }));
}

private class MyCallback implements FutureCallback<Boolean> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final @Nullable Boolean result) {
        ...
        new Pair<Key, Value>() {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

That being said, I'm submitting a more formalized bug report to java soon enough.